# sending memberships in web2py cas

Tags: authentication, web2py, cas

I am fairly new to using Web2py and am trying to get CAS authorisation working from one server(web2py instance) to another.  Specifically I am trying to understand whether I can assign a role to a user on the cas_provider and then query this on the consumer app?

I have managed to create users on the CAS and log them in on the consumer app, but I would like to show them fields of a database that are dependent on their membership to specific groups.  I have a workaround where I have created the groups and memberships in the consumer app, but really I would like to do all this on the CAS to avoid having to make changes in two places every time I add a new user.

In my research online I am getting the impression that CAS may restrict sending membership due to security concerns, but I don't really understand why that should be the case, as it is already sending sensitive information, apparently securely?

Any advice would be very helpful, as the CAS part of web2py seems under-documented for beginners like me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging in via CAS, web2py `Auth` does not provide any built-in facility for checking roles/permissions in the CAS provider app. However, nothing stops you from accessing and querying the CAS provider app database via the DAL. Something like:

```
import os
cas_db_folder = os.path.join(request.folder, '..', 'appname', 'databases')
cas_db = DAL(cas_db_connection_string, folder=cas_db_folder', auto_import=True)
```

Now you can query the `cas_db.auth_user`, `cas_db.auth_group`, and `cas_db.auth_membership` tables to get user roles.

As an alternative, if you have a simple set of roles, you might consider storing them in the `auth_user` table as [extra fields](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Customizing-Auth) (you could store them in a `list:string` field or as a set of boolean fields). If you set up the same set of extra fields in the `auth_user` tables in both the CAS provider app and the CAS consumer app, the values of those fields will be copied from the provider to the consumer. Note, the fields must be set to `readable` for the CAS provider to pass them to the consumer. Also, to ensure the fields are updated in the consumer app after an update in the provider app, be sure to set `auth.settings.update_fields` in the consumer app (it should be a list of field names that you want to make sure get updated, included "email").

Comment: Thanks Anthony,  
This does make sense to me and I will give it a try.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Adding extra fields doesn't seem to work at all.  The fields are just filled with "none" on the consumer app.  Please see my comment above about with the code I am using. I just can't seem to get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer to note the fields must be set to `readable` for the CAS provider to pass them along. Feel free to accept the answer if this works for you.

Comment: I am noticing that if I change a value on the CAS provider the value isn't 'pushed' to the consumer app if the user already exists there.  Am I missing something in my implementation?  I am wondering if I need to put an 'if' statement in somewhere to do a check on the boolean fields...but not sure quite where.

Comment: Try setting `auth.settings.update_fields = ['email', 'other', 'fields']` (note, the update will only happen upon a new login).

Comment: Thanks Anthony, that works great after putting the code on the consumer app db.py.

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra fields doesn't seem to work correctly.  I have added the exact same fields to the CAS and consumer app but the consumer doesn't take the values from the CAS.  I can't see what the problem is, as the email and username all go across fine.  I can see that the fields are created on the Consumer app but they are not populated from the CAS.  They just have 'none' entires.

Here is the CAS code:

```
db.define_table(
auth.settings.table_user_name,

#User Fields for them to fill in
Field('first_name', length=128, required=False, default=''),
Field('last_name', length=128, required=False, default=''),
Field('username', length=128, required=False, default='', unique=True),
Field('email', length=128, required=False, default='', unique=True),
Field('company', length=256, default=''),
Field('address', length=256, default=''),
Field('city', length=128, default=''),
Field('postcode', length=128, default=''),
Field('country', length=128, requires=IS_IN_SET(COUNTRIES)),
Field('password', 'password', length=512, required=False, readable=False, label='Password'),

#Fields that are for administration purposes
Field('date_created', type= 'datetime', default = request.now, requires = IS_DATETIME(format=('%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S GMT')), writable=False),
Field('server_added', type='boolean', writable=False, readable=False, default='False'),
Field('admin_role', type='boolean', writable=False, readable=False, default='False'),
Field('temp_user', type='boolean', writable=False, readable=False, default='False'),

#Fields for web2py internal purposes
Field('registration_key', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
Field('reset_password_key', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),
Field('registration_id', length=512, writable=False, readable=False, default=''),

#This last line states what should be exposed when referencing the table
format='%(username)s  :  %(email)s')

#Setting up Validators
member = db[auth.settings.table_user_name] # get the custom_auth_table
member.first_name.requires = \
IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty)
member.last_name.requires = \
IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message=auth.messages.is_empty)
member.password.requires = [IS_STRONG(min=5, special=0, upper=0), CRYPT()]
member.email.requires = [
IS_EMAIL(error_message=auth.messages.invalid_email),
IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.email')]
member.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.username')
```

Here is Consumer code:

```
#Use the CAS for authentication
auth = Auth(db, cas_provider = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

service = Service()
plugins = PluginManager()

#Add additional field to Auth to accept the ADMIN flag
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
Field('admin_role', type='boolean'),
Field('postcode', length=128, default='')]

## create all tables needed by auth if not custom tables
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)
```

Comment: I finally figured out my problem after poking around in gluon/tools.py.  The issue was that because my field was labelled as readable=FALSE, the CAS couldn't send it.  As soon as I changed that to True, it sent across fine.